# rails model call back before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5.2.3

If I inherits Active Record I can definitely use `before_validation` callback. But I only use `include ActiveModel::Model`
 like this

```
# MortgageAmount model
class MortgageAmount
  include ActiveModel::Model


end
```

It seems I cannot make `before_validation` callback. Should I just include other component to have `before_validation` callback?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin It works! Thanks! If you write an answer I will accept yours!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include [`ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_validation) to get [`before_validation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb#L56) and [`after_validation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb#L97) class methods.

Comment: Actaully we need to include ` include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks` as well.  `include ActiveModel::Validations` not working

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin you only need to `include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks` because `ActiveModel::Model` already includes `ActiveModel::Validations`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks, fixed; I could never understand nor use Rails :(